# How to interact with two different hive Metastores using Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement. Querying a hive table of a one metastore and writing the result of Dataframe into a different hive metastore table. I am using Spark SQL using Spark Scala. I am using Spark 2.1 and saveastable API, Is there any way i can connect to a two diffrent metastores using a spark context?? The challenge here i am facing is in one spark job i can use only one spark context which interacts with one Hive metastore URIS.